# Col in table colgroup is getting hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to develop a fixed header table.It is a kind of widget, where use will be allowed to set width to columns whichever he wants.

**Scenario:**

Table(width is set to `500px`) has four columns where if we don't specify width at `col` tag level,all columns are optimized to total table width like this:

[image]

If we specify width to 2 columns at  `col` level whose total width is less than table width, then table looks like as follow:

[image]

But, if width of the 2 columns are greater than table width, then remaining columns are getting hidden, though table wrapper(`<div class="v-grid-content">`) has `overflow:auto`.Scrolling is enabled but only two fields are shown:
[image]

I am not getting what is wrong, can somebody help. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramstheroyal/c1vmn9tx/2/).

**I tried to keep `min-width` to `col`,but that didn't work.**

Do we need to set width to every `col`??

Comment: @Zhertal  This is a kind of widget, where use will be allowed to set width to column whichever he wants.So lets says he sets table(has 4 columns) width to 300px,1st column width to 150px and 2nd column to 400px but didn't set any width to rest of the columns. As per the problem, the 1st two are shown and other columns are getting hidden. I hope I am clear now!!

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to set width to every col?

No, you don't. You can set a width to some – any other column widths will get computed by the browser as usual. (Taking into account the widest content of that column and the overall table width.)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. But, if you check my jsfiddle, the remaining columns are getting hidden.